# extern template with using type alias

Tags: c++, templates, using, extern

I was wondering if this is a valid compiler error or not and whether the compile is doing the right thing.
Assume a simple template class defined in a header and cpp file.

```
// MyVector.h
template<class T>
class MyVector
{
public:
    MyVector() = default;
    ~MyVector() = default;

    int function();
private :
    T data;
};

// type alias
using MyVecD = MyVector<double>;
```

The cpp file will also include an explicit instantiation of a typical type.

```
// MyVector.cpp
#include "MyVector.h"

template<class T>
int MyVector<T>::function() { return data + 42; }

// explicit instantiation for double
template class MyVector<double>;
```

I would have expected that the type alias would have worked fine but I am not sure.

```
#include "MyVector.h"

// Suppresses implicit instantiation
// No problems here 
extern template class MyVector<double>;
// This fails to compile in VS 2017
// extern template class MyVecD;

int main()
{
    MyVecD test;
    auto result = test.function();

    return 0;
}
```

Even if I cannot use a type alias in the extern, how can I be sure that the compiler is not instantiating my type alias here and is actually doing the right thing.

Comment: You say it fails to compile but you failed to post the error message.

Comment: looks right to me, `MyVecD` is not a class (nor a template), its an alias.

Comment: @JohnZwinck The error message is `error C2371: 'MyVecD': redefinition; different basic types`. It seems that you have marked it as duplicate so if you would not mind posting that duplicate it would be great, cause I certainly did not find anything related to suppressing the implicit instantiation using type aliases. Other than that `extern template MyVecD;` does compile but I dont know if it has the semantics that I would expect or it is something else.

Comment: @vu1p3n0x I thought that as well but then as I mentioned `extern template MyVecD;` does compile fine even though `MyVecD` is a type alias. The question still remain if this indeed supresses the implicit instantiation.

Comment: @xerion: The duplicate is linked right at the top of this page.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Missed that, thank you. Is a type alias really the same as a typedef? As I already said the `extern template MyVecD` actually compiles contrary to what is stated in the post but I am using msvc and not gcc.